# Enhancement in GIF keyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, keyboard, custom-keyboard

At present I am working on GIF keyboard plugin for iOS. 
Following github link give me good start to move ahead.

[SamStone92/kanyekeyboad](https://github.com/SamStone92/kanyekeyboad)

I want to put my custom emojies over custom keyboard. Using above reference project I can able to achieve same thing but in this there is one problem exist and that is very frustrating for end user.

**Problem:** To place any emoji into text area, first you need to click on emoji from keyboard then **Copy** button is available for you, you need to press that.

Then you need to touch on text area, at that time another button with label **Paste** is available on screen. You need to press this button to get actual emoji in text area. I want to remove this.

Following image gives you more idea:

[image]

**Target:** I want to implement, you just need to touch on keyboard emoji and it will directly paste on text area. Like we are doing in Skype or any other messaging application.

Comment: You cannot say this as issue. If you want an additional feature from any open source control. You've to raise a request or you have to implement it with your own risk.

Comment: I have not written anywhere in my question that source, I am using was buggy, I try to say to whatever implementation, I have done that contains this copy-paste issue.

Comment: See, you're trying to copy an *emoji* without tapping any copy button. Right?

Comment: @Praveen, now you are really clear about my problem.

Comment: I'm clear about what you're trying to do. But, the way you have raised this question is totally wrong. You shouldn't say this as issue. You have to implement it with your own risk.

Comment: I want to just get confirmation about, whether this thing is possible in iOS or not?